# Error when using WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

Once I have uploaded the Elise theme I bought from ThemeForest get the following warning messages:

> **Warning:** fopen(/websites/la/launchhousing.org.au/wp-content/languages/es_ES.po) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /websites/la/launchhousing.org.au/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3666
>
> **Warning:** fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /websites/la/launchhousing.org.au/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3669
>
> **Warning:** fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /websites/la/launchhousing.org.au/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3672

Under the 'live preview' I can't see anything except the menu on the left hand side.

I installed WordPress using the one click installer Melbourne IT (my hosting provider) offers.

[Live Site](http://lala16060.staging-cloud.partnerconsole.net/)

How can I fix this?

Comment: error for `fopen()` is that you need change the permissions of the file that you are trying to read, so that it can be read. Error of `fread()` is that you are not passing the file name in the function, format of `fread()` is `fread(youfile,length)`. similarly syntax of `fclose()` is `fclose(yourfilehandle)`;

Comment: Ask this question in the ThemeForest support center for the theme. You will get a better response Josh.

Answer (score -1):

change your theme folder permission with 777 then try again.

Comment: Doing this will fix your problem, but will also make your site vulnerable to security exploits.

Comment: just only for theme upload after them installed you can revert permission .